# Using "now" to start about every other part of your speech

Tags: conjunctions

When I was watching the Apple keynote presentation it occured to me that all the speakers have this habit of starting about every other new part of their speeches with the word "now". This usage of "now" seems to me like a filler word without any meaning.

Of course once I've noticed it, I couldn't unhear it for the rest of the presentation. Such things can become very dominant.

Since I'm not a native English speaker I was wondering:

- Is this habit common among certain groups of people (maybe tech people)?
- Is it bad style or is it just regular English talking?

You can hear an example at https://www.apple.com/apple-events/june-2019/ if you listen to the short section from 00:41:15 bis 00:41:35 for example. He is saying it twice in those 20 seconds.

*Example transcribed:*

[...] You just tap it and you are authenticated with Face ID on your device, logged in with a new account without revealing any new personal information. (Applause) **Now** some apps may want your name, and maybe even an email to send you information when you are outside the app. **Now** we do allow them to request this information, [...]

Comment: Could you please add in some examples of this to your question directly? If Apple change their URL structure or delete the page, your link will be no use anymore and people won’t be able to tell what kind of _now_ you’re talking about.

Comment: Yes, 'filleritis' is a very real and annoying (almost certainly primarily for the speakers themselves) problem. Here's a helpful article, from [TheBalanceSMB.com/speak for success – speech problem of fillers](https://www.thebalancesmb.com/speak-for-success-speech-problem-of-fillers-2948544). Non-seqiturial 'so', and 'y'no' = 'you know' are common offenders.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this use of "now" is quite common. From [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/now):

> You say 'Now' or 'Now then' to indicate to the person or people you are with that you want their attention, or that you are about to change the subject. (spoken)

Here are a few examples:

- Now, what shall we do next?
- Now then, lady, what's the trouble?
- Now, listen everybody!

So, no, it's not common among a particular group of people. It's just common.

It's not bad style. But remember that it's spoken English. If you are in a situation in which more formal language is expected, stay more formal.

Comment: OP asks about possible overuse, not use.